# (1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68) Error when using POST

Tags: http-post, token, laravel-5.4

I have created a contact Form using Laravel 5.4 which works fine when I test on localhost(sends an email to my inbox), when I test on a live server(Hostgator), I get: **(1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)** after pressing the Submit button.I have added a csrf field on the form but the problem persists

```
<form action= "{{ url('contact') }}" method="POST" class="contact-form"  data-parsley-validate =''>
{{ csrf_field() }}

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name..." class="input"  minlength = "13" required>

<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number..." class="input" type="integer" required>

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address..." class="input" required>

<textarea name="message" class="input" minlength="100" rows="10" required> </textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with laravel 5.2 two day ago and my solution was the next:
add this after  whithout spaces inside the {{ }} and work fine